# Instructing a node library to use a wrapper for its calls

Tags: node.js, wrapper

I am using the the following [odata nodejs client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-client):

This library uses nodejs's popular [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library.

For my needs however, I need to use a NTLM wrapper for the request library.

Is there any way to set my nodejs program so that all request calls (gets/ post /puts) initiated by the odata nodejs client library are piped through the wrapper?

Basically, I think I am asking for a way to intercept and pipe the calls through the NTLM wrapper. As I'm typing this, I'm thinking it's not possible and that I would have to modify the odata library to use the NTLM request wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation all of the http methods (for non-batched queries) take an **options** argument which is passed to the underlying request library.

```
 - get(options)
 - post(body, options)
 - put(body, options)
 - patch(body, options)
 - delete(options)
```

You should be able to use this to modify the request with the appropriate NTLM data.

Comment: I've looked around at this quite a bit and due to the nature of NTLM, it doesn't seem that such an option exists...